# Firebase custom authentication, generating uid using SHA256 of email address

Tags: email, hash, firebase, sha256

I'm using custom authentication for Firebase in one of my apps. I'm generating the uid of the user by SHA256 hash of the user's email address.

My question is, how secure is this? Do I need to worry about collisions? Cause if there is a collision it would give complete account access to another user whose email's hash is the same.

If this is not secure can anyone please recommend me a way to generate a unique string from an email address that won't have collisions?

Comment: Is your question "what are the chances of collisions with SHA256 hashes of email addresses?"

Comment: There will always be a chance of collisions when you hash, since that is part of their purpose. You are probably looking to *encrypt* the email address, for example with DES.

Comment: How are you going to handle it when users change their email address?  User A starts with user11@test, then changes to user1@test.  Then User B registers with users11@test.  And for what purpose do you want a uid based on the email address?

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords I'm not going to allow users to change their emails. Each account will have one primary email, if they want to use other email then create another account. And secondly, I'm using email hash because it would make it easier to login with multiple social providers into the same account if their email is the same.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But if I use DES the output would be in bytes, and if I convert it into a string it would be random gibberish having all the unicode characters from 0-255. How would I make it somewhat human readable? If I base64 encode it then I again run into risk of collisions.

Comment: base64 encoding an encrypted string introduces no chance of collisions, since both encryption and base64 are lossless transformations. The goal of encryption is to make a meaningful string look like random gibberish, isn't it? ;-) Otherwise why don't you use the email address as the id (replacing dots with commas)?